# AWS signature version 4 sha256 hash not signing correctly?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, signature, sha256

I am trying to use the AWS signature version 4 to submit a request to S3.

When I submit my request I get the message 
`The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.`

I am not sure where to go from here. I have tried several different hash algorithms (sha1, md5) but always get the same response. I have verified the Access Key and Secret Key. I just created a new one pair on AWS, and it still fails.

Any help is appreciated!

```html
<?php
$date = date('Ymd');
$x_date = $date . "T000000Z";
$credential = AWS_ACCESS_KEY . '/' . $date . '/us-west-2/s3/aws4_request';
$redirect = 'https://roofscope.com/scope/thank-you';

$conditions = array(
 array('bucket' => 'tracescope'),
 array('starts-with', '$key', 'user/user1/'),
 array('acl' => 'public-read'),
 array('success_action_redirect' => $redirect),
 array("starts-with", "\$Content-Type", "image/"),
 array("x-amz-credential" => $credential),
 array("x-amz-algorithm"=> "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256"),
 array("x-amz-date" => $x_date),
);

$policy_b64 = $this->aws->getPolicy(3600 * 24, $conditions);
$signature = hash_hmac('sha256', $policy_b64, AWS_SECRET_KEY);
?>

<form action="http://tracescope.s3.amazonaws.com/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type="input" name="key" value="test/${filename}"/><br/>
 <input type="hidden" name="acl" value="public-read"/>
 <input type="hidden" name="success_action_redirect" value="<?= $redirect; ?>"/>
 <input type="input" name="Content-Type" value="image/jpeg"/><br/>
 <input type="text" name="X-Amz-Credential" value="<?= $credential; ?>"/>
 <input type="text" name="X-Amz-Algorithm" value="AWS4-HMAC-SHA256"/>
 <input type="text" name="X-Amz-Date" value="<?= $x_date; ?>"/>
 <input type="hidden" name="Policy" value="<?= $policy_b64; ?>" />
 <input type="hidden" name="X-Amz-Signature" value="<?= $signature; ?>"/>

 <input type="file" name="file"/> <br/>

 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload to Amazon S3"/>
</form>
```

Comment: I'm having problems with this too, I tried using the signature tester and the Signature (using secret key) shows up different from the signature my code generates, but when I hardcode the new signature in the html I get the same error when uploading...

Comment: Hi, I've encountered the same problem with ruby. It worked for me using SHA1. you can take a look at my [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29081794/browser-based-uploads-using-post)
Have you succeeded to upload using AWSv4?

Answer (score 1):

try using my s3 policy signature verifier.
please do not key in your actual key.
use an example key and test the calculation for the example key on your side as well.

http://ttwd80.github.io/s3postcalculatorverify/

there is a "Show / hide step" link that explains the process step by step.

Comment: I tried your verifier with the data given on http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-post-example.html, but got a signature of 8afdbf400..... and not the one given on that page (46503978d3....). Is the aws documentation wrong?