# Browser-Based Uploads Using POST

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to create a client side uploads using POST with Signature Version 4 of AWS.
According to the documents

When i'm generating the signature on the server side I get an exact match with AWS signature mentioned in [this example page.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-post-example.html)

However when I use it to upload the page I get this error:

> SignatureDoesNotMatchThe request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method

This is the code I've used:

```
OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest('sha256', signing_key(string_to_sign), string_to_sign)  

# step 2 in the aws documentation
def signing_key(encoded_policy)
  # generate the correct date
  date = extract_encoded_policy_date(encoded_policy)
  date = time_adjust(date)

  # encode all the fields by the algorithm
  date_key = OpenSSL::HMAC.digest('sha256',"AWS4#{@secret_access_key}", date.strftime("%Y%m%d"))
  date_region_key = OpenSSL::HMAC.digest('sha256',date_key, @region)
  date_region_service_key = OpenSSL::HMAC.digest('sha256',date_region_key, @service)
  signing_key = OpenSSL::HMAC.digest('sha256',date_region_service_key, 'aws4_request')

  signing_key
end

def time_adjust(date)
  time = Time.parse(date)
  time += time.utc_offset
  time.utc
end
```

After a little search in the net, i've encountered this [article](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1434).    Iv'e implemented this code and the upload succeeded.

````
signature = OpenSSL::HMAC.digest( OpenSSL::Digest::Digest.new('sha1'), @secret_access_key, string_to_sign)
Base64.encode64(signature).gsub("\n","")```
````

This is a small [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5nptnfu9/) for the client side code.

here is some literature I've found useful:
[General description](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sig-v4-authenticating-requests.html)
[Some code snippets from AWS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-v4-examples.html#signature-v4-examples-ruby)

What is the differences between the two?
How can I get the first option to work and upload my files?
Is the example in the AWS page no longer valid?

Comment: It appears you are signing data multiple times. All you need to do is compile the string and sign it once.

Comment: as you can see in this http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sig-v4-authenticating-requests.html, the AWS4 authorization requires a series of encodings.   the second code section was a different try and came instead of the first one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a research and comparing the [AWS post example](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-post-example.html) i found out that there were some redundant fields in the form that made AWS think i'm using SHA1.

After removing the AWSAccessKeyId field from the form and renaming some other fields I managed to make the AWS4 work.

This is the updated [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5nptnfu9/1/)

```
 <form id="myForm" action="http://yourbucket.s3.amazonaws.com/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="hidden" id="key" name="key" value="uploads/${filename}"/>
      <input type="hidden" id="acl" name="acl" value="YOUR_ACL_OPTION"/>
      <input type="hidden" name="success_action_redirect" value="http://google.com" />

      <input type="hidden" id="type" name="Content-Type" value="MIME_TYPE"/>
      <input type="hidden" name="x-amz-meta-uuid" value="14365123651274" />
      <input type="hidden"   name="X-Amz-Credential" value="YOUR_CREDENTIALS" />
      <input type="hidden"   name="X-Amz-Algorithm" value="AWS4-HMAC-SHA256" />
      <input type="hidden" id="date" name="X-Amz-Date" value="" />

      <input type="hidden"  name="x-amz-meta-tag" value="" />
      <input type="hidden" id="policy" name="Policy" value="YOUR_POLICY_DOCUMENT_BASE64_ENCODED"/>
      <input type="hidden" id="signature" name="X-Amz-Signature" value="YOUR_CALCULATED_SIGNATURE"/>

      <input name="file" id="file" type="file"/> 
      <input id="btn_submit" class="btn btn-warning" type="submit" value="Upload File to S3"> 
 </form>
```